# Is this system linear? Can I apply crammer?

Tags: math, machine-learning, linear-algebra, linear-regression

There is this website http://www.diabloprogress.com/items/ that has it's own criterias (unknown to me) calculating a rating for each item. I am not interested if those criterias or weights are right or wrong.

However the question is if I could take the data from each item and make 3x3 matrices, find the det of each matrice and calculate 3 weights using Crammer as in x = Det(x)/D, y = Det(y)/D etc.

Or in other words would that system be linear or not?

More specifically

I would be interested in the attributes: "damage per second", "primary stat (strength or dex or int but not vitality", "crit multiplier"

Or the 3x3 system

```
1456x + 538y + 291z = 2909
1390x + 560y + 300z = 2898
1433x + 527y + 294z = 2871
```

Comment: Crammer? What does "damage per second" have to do with anything in this question? Perhaps you need to start with basic linear algebra.

Comment: He probably understood linear algebra right up to pseudoinverses and SVD. Trying to find an answer to a practical question of interest is a great motivator.

Comment: @dan3 - I seriously doubt he understands anything like the svd OR a pseudo-inverse, or for that matter, a regular inverse, since he apparently wants to use Crammer's rule.

Comment: @woodchips, yes, I meant "right-up-to" as in "not-including". But using some ML to optimize Diablo market transactions would actually be cool.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should provide an actual link that displays a list of items with the three attributes. You can't expect people to guess that "damage per second" corresponds to "Weapon DPS" on the site.

You can always set up a 3x3 linear system and express 3 scores in terms of 3 attributes. But then if you take a different set of 3 items, the weights you have calculated might give you unrealistic scores.

What you want to do is apply [linear regression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regression) to a set of N items and M attributes (M < N). This will give you a vector of M weights that, when multiplied by a vector of item attributes, will estimate the item's score. The estimate will not be perfect, but it will be "minimum-error".

This is a simple form of machine learning. To learn more you could also try the [Machine Learning](https://class.coursera.org/ml/lecture/preview) lectures on Coursera.

If you find that linear regression doesn't give you realistic estimates, you will need to upgrade to a more complicated model.